# Implementing zoom along the gun

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making some game, and I have made it pretty much all, but not zoom along the gun ability, 'cause I have no clue how to set up it. The game is done in 3D using openGL, so I would like to hear your propositions for how to implement it.  If required, snippets of the code can be delivered.

Comment: In DX this is usually done by shortening and widening the angle of the camera lens to the side IIRC.

Comment: so I would use something like glOrtho and project the scene so that it uses only shorter projection of the sight? Along with it, I should also manipulate with the size of the objects?

Comment: There's an example on [this page](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm). It looks like it uses the field of view thing.

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was being looking for! :) You can make an answer, so I can give you credits. Thanks, @chris

Comment: It's already an answer; no need for duplicates of the same thing. I like how that one's a real application as well.

Comment: OK! Thanks on the effort then! :) If you don't mind I will give credits to ananthonline, since he gave me an example! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Quake 3 "zoom" effect was implemented by changing the FOV of the perspective camera. Look [here](http://www.quakewiki.net/archives/code3arena/tutorials/tutorial28.shtml).